# Upload image to Wordpress.com Gallery with REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, image, rest-client, wordpress.com

I'm trying to upload an image to a WordPress.com blog via their REST API.  According to their [documentation](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/post/sites/%24site/posts/new/), I should be able to use the `new post` endpoint to do so.  I'm currently using Rails and [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) to successfully create text posts using the following code (`post_hash` contains all the post information):

```
  url = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/" + @blog.external_id + "/posts/new"
  params = {
      pretty = true,
      title: post_hash[:post_title],
      content: post_hash[:post_content],
      categories: post_hash[:terms_names][:category],
      tags: post_hash[:terms_names][:post_tag]
  }
  headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + @oauth_token, content_type: :json }
  RestClient.post(url, params, headers)
```

As I mentioned, this works perfectly.  Now, I'd like to be able to upload a new image to the blog's Gallery by creating a new "post" with the image attached.  I'm trying to use this code to do so (`image` is a [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) file stored on Amazon S3):

```
  url = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/" + @blog.external_id + "/posts/new"
  image_data = open(image.to_s, "rb").read
  params = {
      format: "image", 
      media: [image_data], 
      multipart: true
  }
  headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + @oauth_token, content_type: image.content_type }
  RestClient.post(url, params, headers)
```

This does not work and keeps giving me a `400 Bad Request` error.  If anyone has any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong or advice on a better way of doing this, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: What was the solution for this 400 bad request issue? I have the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623898/invoke-restmethod-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request