# Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: rest, powershell

I am trying to edit a post with Wordpress on my website and no way, I have no idea why it does not work.

Receiving an Access Token : OK

Validating Tokens : OK

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token-info?client_id=$clientID&token=$token"
```

It is OK, I get the following :

```
{
    "client_id": "your client ID",
    "user_id": "user ID",
    "blog_id": "blog ID",
    "scope": "scope of the token"
}
```

The authentication is OK, my token is valid, I don't think its authentication related.

But when I run this code, I get always :

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand



$body = @{Content="This is a test";Title="Test"} | ConvertTo-Json
$token = 'abcdefs21ds1ds1ds1dsd2s1d2'

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.domain.com/posts/1234" -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Documentation : https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/posts/%24post_ID/

Comment: I'm looking over the documentation, try to run this request using the SiteID instead of the domain?  You can get your site ID by viewing your site, viewing source, then searching for 'blog='.  It will be an integer about 8 digits long.

Comment: I am going to test and I go back here to tell you. Thanks

Comment: I tried using the SiteID and it's the same issue. Anyway, in the documentation it's written that Site ID (int) or domain (string) are both supported.

Comment: Try converting your headers to JSON as well.

Comment: I converted the headers to JSON, it does not work. Error : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "{
    "Authorization":  "Bearer "
}" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary"